# T-SQL - empty CASE + select

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have problem with one query. This work:

```
select coalesce(((SUM(ati.anDebit) - SUM(ati.ancredit))),0) + 
        (select coalesce((SUM(anDebit)),0)  
        from tHE_AcctTransItem where acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523' and     SUBSTRING(acDoc,4,3) in ('391', '3B0') 
        and SUBSTRING(acKey, 3, 3) = '420' and acSubject = 'Company' and acAcct = '1200')
from tHE_AcctTransItem ati inner join tHE_AcctTrans at 
on ati.acKey = at.acKey 
where at.acDocType in('4100', '4620', '4630', '4700', '4730') 
and acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523' and acAcct = '1200' 
and acSubject = 'Company'
```

For my purpose I need to put CASE, and I write this:

```
select case when acDocType <> '4730' then (coalesce(((SUM(ati.anDebit) - SUM(ati.ancredit))),0) + 
    (select coalesce((SUM(anDebit)),0)  
    from tHE_AcctTransItem where acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523' and SUBSTRING(acDoc,4,3) in ('391', '3B0') 
    and SUBSTRING(acKey, 3, 3) = '420' and acSubject = 'Company' and acAcct = '1200')) 
else  coalesce(((SUM(ati.anDebit) - SUM(ati.ancredit))),0) * -1 
end from tHE_AcctTransItem ati inner join tHE_AcctTrans at on ati.acKey = at.acKey where at.acDocType in('4100', '4620', '4630', '4700', '4730') and acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523' and acAcct = '1200' and acSubject = 'Company' group by acDocType
```

But I don't receive anything.

```
select ati.* from tHE_AcctTransItem ati inner join tHE_AcctTrans at on ati.acKey = at.acKey  where at.acDocType in('4100', '4620', '4630', '4700', '4730') and acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523' and acAcct = '1200' and acSubject = 'Company'
```

This does not return any row, and I don't know how to show me result like in first query but with case.
From this query only this select has some data:

```
(select coalesce((SUM(anDebit)),0)  
        from tHE_AcctTransItem where acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523' and     SUBSTRING(acDoc,4,3) in ('391', '3B0') 
        and SUBSTRING(acKey, 3, 3) = '420' and acSubject = 'Company' and acAcct = '1200')
```

And when I put case this is not suming.

Comment: Why all the parentheses?

Comment: I do this in ERP, where I need make on different way. So I write in this ERP and testing in SQL Managment tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your SQL has a lot of extra parentheses, which along with the rather haphazard formatting makes it very hard to read and debug.

Aggregate functions in the select clause of a query that does not have a group by clause will return a null record.

```
declare @t table (
    k nvarchar(50),
    val int
)

select sum(val), avg(val), min(val), max(val) from @t
```

The above returns one row with all nulls. That allows you to wrap your aggregates in the coalesce function and causes the subqueries in the select clause to function.

However, add a group by clause to the query and you no longer get the null row.

```
declare @t table (
    k nvarchar(50),
    val int
)

select sum(val), avg(val), min(val), max(val) from @t group by k
```

The above returns no records at all, so subqueries in the select clause do not run.

You might try something like the following. If the first query returns no records, the second query gets a chance. (Note though that both queries run regardless, so if the queries are data intensive you might want to find another way.)

```
select coalesce((
    select 
        case 
            when acDocType <> '4730' 
            then 
                SUM(ati.anDebit) - SUM(ati.ancredit) + 
                (
                    select
                        coalesce(SUM(anDebit),0)  
                    from 
                        tHE_AcctTransItem 
                    where 
                        acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523' 
                        and SUBSTRING(acDoc,4,3) in ('391', '3B0') 
                        and SUBSTRING(acKey, 3, 3) = '420' 
                        and acSubject = 'Company' 
                        and acAcct = '1200'
                ) 
            else 
                SUM(ati.anDebit) - SUM(ati.ancredit) * -1 
            end 
    from 
        tHE_AcctTransItem ati 
        inner join tHE_AcctTrans at on ati.acKey = at.acKey 
    where 
        at.acDocType in('4100', '4620', '4630', '4700', '4730') 
        and acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523' 
        and acAcct = '1200' 
        and acSubject = 'Company' 
    group by
        acDocType
),(
    select 
        coalesce(SUM(anDebit),0)
    from
        tHE_AcctTransItem
    where
        acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523' 
        and SUBSTRING(acDoc,4,3) in ('391', '3B0') 
        and SUBSTRING(acKey, 3, 3) = '420' 
        and acSubject = 'Company' 
        and acAcct = '1200'
))
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the subquery your SELECT clause:

```
SELECT coalesce(SUM(anDebit), 0)
FROM tHE_AcctTransItem
WHERE acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523'
    AND SUBSTRING(acDoc, 4, 3) IN (
        '391',
        '3B0'
        )
    AND SUBSTRING(acKey, 3, 3) = '420'
    AND acSubject = 'Company'
    AND acAcct = '1200'
```

Is the only query here that is returning data. In your first query you get results back because this subquery is blindly returning data back into the query. You probably get a single record back from it, and then that single amount makes up the entire amount returned in the overall query. For fun, compare just this subquery to your entire first query results. My bet is that they will be the same.

The second query, with the CASE statement fails because now the results of this subquery are restricted to only return when acDocType <> '4730'. Since your query:

```
select ati.* from tHE_AcctTransItem ati inner join tHE_AcctTrans at on ati.acKey = at.acKey  where at.acDocType in('4100', '4620', '4630', '4700', '4730') and acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523' and acAcct = '1200' and acSubject = 'Company'
```

Isn't returning anything, it suggests that your JOIN is bad, or your WHERE statement restricts out every single record. Therein is your problem. I would spend some time looking at the data is returned in that more simplified select statement there but with most of the stuff removed from the WHERE statement.

Comment: JOINI it's good, but in this example they don't return anything, but:
    `select ati.* from tHE_AcctTransItem ati inner join tHE_AcctTrans at on ati.acKey = at.acKey  where at.acDocType in('4200') and acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523' and acAcct = '1200' and acSubject = 'Company' `
return, and that's why I need suming this 2 on 2 different way.

Comment: But you don't have an `at.acDocType` of type '4200' in your queries that are returning 0 records. So... in acDocTypes '4100', '4620', '4630', '4700', and '4730' you have 0 records and in acDotTypes '4200' you have some records. If you want acDoctype of `4200` in your query, perhaps add that in to your `WHERE` clause. I guess, in other words, your question amounts to: "I have a query that returns 0 records because there are no records that match my `WHERE` conditions, but I want it to return records". So... you'll have to change WHERE statement, or you'll have to change your data.

Comment: Sorry.. I'm rereading my words and I think I'm coming off as cranky. I don't mean to sound cranky or short. Your question is good and your SQL is complex. I think I need more coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, if your first query returns results and the third query does not, then the difference must be causing the issue. Notice that your subquery in the first query, is not correlated to the main from and where clauses.  Try this query.  I would

```
SELECT  at.acDocType ,
        ati.acDoc ,
        ati.acKey ,
        SUM(COALESCE(ati.anDebit, 0)) ,
        SUM(COALESCE(ATI.anCredit, 0))
FROM    tHE_AcctTransItem ati
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tHE_AcctTrans at ON ati.acKey = at.acKey
WHERE   ( at.acDocType IN ( '4100', '4620', '4630', '4700', '4730' )
          OR ( SUBSTRING(ati.acDoc, 4, 3) IN ( '391', '3B0' )
               AND SUBSTRING(ati.acKey, 3, 3) = '420'
             )
        )
        AND ati.acLinkDoc = '15-390-000523'
        AND ati.acAcct = '1200'
        AND ati.acSubject = 'Company'
GROUP BY ALL at.acDocType ,
        ati.acDoc ,
        ati.acKey
```

I expect that you will see the null results that are created by one of your joins in the main query.